# Isolate dictionary keys which have multiple duplicate values

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

```
d = {'Name1': ['Male', '18'],
     'Name2': ['Male', '16'], 
     'Name3': ['Male', '18'],
     'Name4': ['Female', '18'], 
     'Name5': ['Female', '18']}
```

I am trying to find a way to isolate the duplicate keys to a list if any. Like:

```
['Name1', 'Name3']
['Name4', 'Name5']
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
d = {'Name1': ['Male', '18'],
 'Name2': ['Male', '16'], 
 'Name3': ['Male', '18'],
 'Name4': ['Female', '18'], 
 'Name5': ['Female', '18']}

ages = {} #create a dictionary to hold items with identical ages

#loop over all the items in the dictionary
for key in d.keys():
    age = d[key][1]

    #if the ages dictionary still does not have an item 
    #for the age we create an array to hold items with the same age
    if(age not in ages.keys()):
        ages[age] = [] 

    ages[age].append(key) #finally append items with the same ages together

#loop over all the items in the ages dictionary
for value in ages.values():
    if(len(value) > 1):#if we have more than one item in the ages dictionary
        print(value) #print it
```

Answer (score 2):

An imperative solution would be to just iterate over the dictionary and add the items into another dictionary that uses the gender-age-tuple as a key, for example:

```
# using a defaultdict, which automatically adds an empty list for missing keys when first accesses
from collections import defaultdict
by_data = defaultdict(list) 
for name, data in d.items():
    # turn the data into something immutable, so it can be used as a dictionary key
    data_tuple = tuple(data)
    by_data[data_tuple].append(name)
```

the result will be:

```
{('Female', '18'): ['Name4', 'Name5'],
 ('Male', '16'): ['Name2'],
 ('Male', '18'): ['Name1', 'Name3']})
```

You can filter out entries with only one value, if you are only interested in duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you meant duplicate values and not keys, in which case you could do this with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T #load the data into a dataframe, and transpose it
df.index[df.duplicated(keep = False)]
```

`df.duplicated(keep = False)` gives you a series of True/False, where the value is `True` whenever that item has a duplicate, and False otherwise. We use that to index the row names, which is `'Name1','Name2'`, etc.